# Powershell PS Credentials

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm getting confused while trying to automatically login to a share on my server through Powershell using PSCredentials.

Here is the code I'm currently using WITHOUT using PSCredentials...

```
#Login to server to copy installer files to desktop
Remove-PSDrive P
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\192.168.1.85\Users2\Ross\Documents\Powershell -Credential Ross
#Copies installer files from server to the local desktop
Copy-Item -Path \\192.168.1.85\Users2\Ross\Documents\Powershell\ccsetup502.exe -Destination C:\Users\Ross\Desktop
#Executes copied installers
Start-Process C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\ccsetup502.exe -ArgumentList "/S" -Wait -Verb RunAs
#Deletes leftover installer files
Remove-Item C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\ccsetup502.exe
```

And here is the website I'm using to help, but whichever way I try and apply it to my own script, it never works?

http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/02/16/106518.aspx

Thanks in advance!

Ross

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line - the New-PSDrive line or the Copy-Item line?

Comment: `Ross` is not a credential object. You could use `-Credential (Get-Credential Ross)` which would prompt you for a user name and password (with the user name pre-filled to "Ross"). But it would be helpful to know the information that @KeithHill asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will prompt you for creds, but you could always create them and store them in a variable if you wish as well.

```
#Login to server to copy installer files to desktop
Remove-PSDrive P
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\192.168.1.85\Users2\Ross\Documents\Powershell -Credential (Get-Credential)
#Copies installer files from server to the local desktop
Copy-Item -Path \\192.168.1.85\Users2\Ross\Documents\Powershell\ccsetup502.exe -Destination C:\Users\Ross\Desktop
#Executes copied installers
Start-Process C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\ccsetup502.exe -ArgumentList "/S" -Wait -Verb RunAs
#Deletes leftover installer files
Remove-Item C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\ccsetup502.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

After some perseverance I managed to solve this...

Probably worth noting that I left the PSDrive removal in there for testing purposes, as you'll get an error if the script doesn't complete and you try to run it again after making changes.

```
#Ensure previous PSDrive 'p' is removed
Remove-PSDrive P
#Creates new PSDrive
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\YOURSERVERNAMEHERE\YOURFILEPATHHERE
#Login to server
new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "YOURDOMAINORSERVERUSERNAMEHERE",$password
#Copies installer files from server to the local desktop
Copy-Item -Path \\YOURSERVERNAMEHERE\YOURFILEPATHHERE\ccsetup502.exe -Destination C:\YOURFILEPATHHERE
#Executes copied installers, runs the installer silently, waits until the installer has completed
Start-Process C:\YOURFILEPATHHERE\ccsetup502.exe -ArgumentList "/S" -Wait -Verb RunAs
#Deletes leftover installer files
Remove-Item C:\YOURFILEPATHHERE\ccsetup502.exe
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who is stuck in the future!

Thank you anyone else who contributed their efforts.